# Checking the history of www-data user

Tags: apache-2.2, bash, www-data

While normal users have a `.bash_history` in their home directory, the `www-data` user does not have a home directory.

As such, are there any means to track the history of the `www-data` user?

Comment: Why would anyone be running bash as www-data in the first place?

Comment: i was thinking along the lines of finding out which scripts / processes ran by www-data recently. mainly for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: `.bash_history` is not a logfile. It is tool to aid interactive shells. The main purpose is that commands you have previously used in an interactive shell can be recalled in case you need to execute the same or a very similar command at a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process accounting could help your cause. If your kernel supports process accounting, which is something normally supported by kernels provided by distribution you need to enable process accounting by running

> acct on

If you don't have `acct` you will need to install process accounting tools, e.g.

On centos/redhat

> yum install psacct

On debian/ubuntu

> apt-get install acct

and then to check what some user was running you can use

> lastcomm www-data